# Facebook Debugger needs several refreshes before returning proper og:image value

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Facebook Debugger to consistently solve a problem with og:image tags that we are using on an AngularJS site. My content editor has to clear caches in FB several times before getting the correct meta to come through. Here is our setup:

1. We are using a PhantomJS, disk cache enabled look aside for all UA ~ Facebook to properly pass FB requests to our static HTML markup. We have verified (via `curl 'http://localhost:9000/path/to/my/page' | grep og:image`) that the proper og:image tag is present before trying to share or present a new object to the FB Open Graph
2. We have to consistently "Fetch new scrape information" 3 - 4 times before FB Debugger pulls the proper image. The debugger returns scrapes in the following way:

-- First fetch: Default og tags before Angular bindings hit.

It's hard to say why this is happening since we haven't tried to share the page previously. We've passed the page into the PhantomJS process and seen the proper og in the returns (in order to cache the return before sharing or heading to FB).

-- Second fetch: Proper og tags filled in with desired image but with the OG Image warning

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'XXXXXXX' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.

The desired image is 600x337 png (no transparency) so size isn't an issue (and it eventually shows). The fallback image being used instead is the default og:image previous from scrape #1.

-- Third fetch:

OG Image warning is gone and all additional fetches return the proper meta. Sharing works and we can move on.

So while this works, it is a little heavy handed. Clearly we have an issue with FB seeing our default meta, caching that meta, and needing us to clear things out. Before we implement any cache warming in out PhantomJS process, and possibly a POST to the FB API to get the proper scrape markup into Open Graph, can someone answer why the additional 2nd refresh produces the og:image warning and then it goes away? If the proper og:image exists and is correctly sized, why the error?

[We looked at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617847/ogimage-was-not-defined-could-not-be-downloaded-or-was-not-big-enough-error-d), and the comment says to clear our browser cache when using the debugger. We've considered the comment to use multiple browsers but to no avail. We've tried cache-less POSTs using Postman to test this theory as it may be how we cache warm but still see the need for the additional refreshes.

Comment: FYI: Something went wrong with your link near the end. The URL for [1] is missing. Welcome to StackOverflow, btw!

Comment: Thanks nate. I'm not sure what happened there either. There reference is for this question and I've edited the original.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617847/ogimage-was-not-defined-could-not-be-downloaded-or-was-not-big-enough-error-d

Comment: If this is only happening when cache is enabled then this might be an issue from your side?